GCP CloudRun startup probe fails after 7 attempts even though failureThreshold is set to 30
I have a GCP cloudRun container which I have configured with the following values for the startup probe (I confirmed they are correctly set on the revision)

initial delay 100s
timeout 10s
failure threshold 30
interval 10s

Now the problem I have is that the container still does not startup correctly and in the console I find the error
STARTUP HTTP probe failed 7 times consecutively for container
This confuses me since I expected 30 attempts to be made, not just 7 - I have no idea where the 7 is coming from and why my configured failure threshold is ignored.
I triple checked the configuration in the GUI and I definetly have 30 as a failure threshold (for the liveness probe it's 6 so that is also not where the 7 is coming from)
I'm grateful for any advice

after playing around a bit more the issue apparently was the 240s max startup duration. While the error message is misleading I was able to come to that conclusion because if I increase the initial delay to 200 I get the error
STARTUP HTTP probe failed 2 times consecutively for container "log-cleanups-1" on path "/api/checks/warmup". The instance was not started.
so it seems to be that the timeout was just reached
